# How to manage Excel With Delphi 7 using paradox file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I open Excel file in Delphi 7 and move the data to a paradox file?

Answer (score 2):

Using the Ado_**__** components From the ADO tab.
To "connect" with the file use the TAdoConnection then double-click it, in the provider tab you must select "Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider", in the connection tab you put the name of the file relative to the current directory of your process, in the fourth tab in extended properties you select the version of excel that you want to use.
Note: This connection only works at runtime.

Now you can add an TAdoQuery and link it up with the TAdoConnection, in this query you can use SQL DML statements like select, insert (didn't try this one) and update, delete doesn't work, the only trick is that instead of using table names in the from clause you use excel ranges, for example A range from the A1 cell to to the C10 cell on the sheet MySheet1: [MySheet1$A1:c10], here's the full select for this range:

```
Select *
From [MySheet1$A1:c10]
```

You can also use named ranges [MyNamedRangeName$] and entire sheets: [MyEntireSheet$] (notice the mandatory $ after the names).

Now with the data in a dataset you should be able to move it to the paradox dataset.

This about.com article explains in more detail: http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa090903a.htm